# How to set env variables from root env file while building docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I've folder structure like this,

```
service-1
- Dockerfile
service-2
- Dockerfile
.env
docker-compose.yml
```

Now I need to get it working in a way that Dockerfile can access root level `.env` file while building services.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of what's in this file that you need it at image build time?  (Many of the things I'd expect to see in a `.env` file are runtime configuration like host names, and you would not build them into your image typically.)  What have you tried already?

Comment: basically, I need .env file while I'm building a particular service. like if I'm building service-1 then in the build process of docker It'll include the root level `.env` file. so, service-1 doesn't need any extra env file to run.